# How to capture text inside <TAGs> , BUT by excluding the tags from result?

Tags: regex, vb.net, text, capture

In Visual Basic I am trying to get text between tags but TAGS are also captured.

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim pattern As String = "<tag>(.+?)<\/tag>"
    Dim text As String = "Other Text <tag>Captured Text</tag> Other Text"
    Dim capture As Match = Regex.Match(text, pattern)
    MsgBox(capture.Value)
End Sub
```

I want to see the result as ONLY "Captured Text" in message box.

But result is coming as "...Captured Text...." with both tags before and after .

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should access Group 1 value:

```
MsgBox(capture.Groups(1).Value)
```

The pattern you use contains a capturing group defined with a pair of unescaped parentheses, and that part makes the regex engine to store the value captured inside some memory  buffer. There are as many such memory  buffers as there are capturing groups plus a group with index 0 that holds the whole match value. You need to access the Group 1 value.

Also note that `capture` variable name is misleading here since a capture is a value stored inside a group stack and `Regex.Match` returns a `Match` object containing all group and capture values and some information about them.

Comment: Yes, Groups(1) is the solution..Thank you very much.